# Trying to get property 'addressLine1' of non-object in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, associative-array

hello guys i have been trying to access the value through multidimensional array in laravel view

my json array is

```html
{
"results":[
{
"id":4582,
"name":"Rocklands Bouldering Permit",
"description":"This permit guarantees entry to all bouldering areas in Rocklands for the validity duration, including CapeNature, de Pakhuys and Travellers Rest<br><u><strong>All climbers visiting Rocklands must be in possession of this permit to climb on any land and must carry this permit with them at all times </strong></u>.<br><br><strong>Booking Terms and Conditions:</strong><br>The following Terms and Conditions apply to all bookings (walk-in or pre-paid):<br><br>Damage / loss / death<br><br>It is a distinct condition of admission to any protected area, that the Western Cape Nature Conservation Board and the property owners accept no responsibility or liability arising from a visit(s) <br><br>howsoever caused:<ul><li>For any death, injury or illness sustained or suffered by any person.</li><li>For theft/loss/damage to any property, whether allegedly due to the negligence of the board/</li><li>officers/employees/agents or arising from the use of any facilities supplied/made available.</li><li>CapeNature and the landowners accepts NO responsibility for clothing or any items left behind at our facilities.</li><li>From any alleged defect in any utensil/equipment/services/vessel/vehicle.</li><li>From any other conveyance supplied/made available, or from any liquid/food supplied.</li><li>From any other matter arising, in any other manner and from any other cause whatsoever.</li></ul><br><strong>Breaking of the rules</strong><br>CapeNature and the landowners reserves the right to deny access or to evict guests who do not adhere to the rules and regulations of the CapeNature and landowners and/or its reserves. Money paid for these bookings will be forfeited.<br><br><em><strong>These rules include, but are not limited to the following:</strong></em><ul><li>Visitors are to have their bouldering permit with them upon entrance to the reserve.</li><li>No pets allowed on reserves, the only exception will be guide dogs for the blind.</li><li>No collection of bait, removing, damaging or disturbing of fauna or flora</li><li>Rowdy or unwanted behavior</li><li>All tariffs are subject to change without notification.</li><li>Stick to the marked walking trails</li><li>No puff or resin allowed</li><li>Carry out what you carry in</li></ul>",
"url":"https://www.quicket.co.za/events/4582-rocklands-bouldering-permit/",
"imageUrl":"//quicket.azureedge.net/media/0004303_360_360.Png",
"dateCreated":"2014-03-12T16:59:47.467",
"lastModified":"2018-05-31T10:27:35.4102002",
"startDate":"2014-03-13T10:24:00",
"endDate":"2024-03-01T10:24:00",
"venue":{
"id":0,
"name":"Rocklands",
"addressLine1":"",
"addressLine2":"",
"latitude":-32.1786111,
"longitude":18.8911111
},
{
"id":2830,
"name":"ROX TEST EVENT",
"description":"<span style=\"line-height: 20.7999992370605px;\">Description of the event will go here</span><br /><br /><span style=\"line-height: 20.7999992370605px;\">And you can add pictures or even a youtube video or two here! You can also add a <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.rockingthedaisies.com\">hyperlink</a></span><br /><br /><br /><iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/soyeZp_3qN4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"\"></iframe>",
"url":"https://www.quicket.co.za/events/2830-rox-test-event/",
"imageUrl":"//quicket.azureedge.net/media/0007888_360_360.Jpeg",
"dateCreated":"2013-09-11T13:14:01.283",
"lastModified":"2018-06-05T10:29:28.574536",
"startDate":"2015-05-07T15:17:00",
"endDate":"2024-05-14T00:00:00",
"venue":{
"id":0,
"name":"Roxys cafe ",
"addressLine1":"14 Wandel Street",
"addressLine2":"",
"latitude":-33.931801,
"longitude":18.417017999999985
}
]
```

i wanted to get the value of "name" inside results array which i am able to get in my blade view but when i am trying to access "addressLine1" and "addressLine2" from my blade i am unable to get that and i can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code.

following is my code in blade

```html
 @foreach($datas as $data=>$key)
            @for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
                <h1>{{$datas[$data][$i]['name']}}</h1>
            @endfor
            @if(is_array($key))
                @foreach($key as $k=>$v)
                    @if(is_array($v))
                        @foreach($v as $venue=>$place)
                            {{dd($place['venue']->addressLine1)}}
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

and this is the error i am getting
Trying to get property 'addressLine1' of non-object

Please help me out here Thanks in advance

P.S $datas is my json encoded array from controller

Answer (score 0):

Your json has syntax error. If this is the json you pass to the blade, it may be the problem. What is the controller code?

Comment: public function getRemoteData(){
        $client= new Client([
            'headers'=>['content-type'=>'application/json','Accept'=> 'aaplication/json']
        ]);
        $response= $client->request('GET','URL(not pasting here because of security');
        $json=$response->getbody();
        $datas=json_decode($json,true);
        //print_r($data);

        //$data=array($datas);
        
        return view('index',compact('datas'));
        //return view('index')->with('data', json_decode($data, true));
    }

this is my controller code

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys i solved the error but now foreach is repeating the same result 10 times for no reason at all how do i stop that?

here is my edited code in blade

```
@foreach($datas as $data=>$key)
        @for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
            <h1>{{$datas[$data][$i]['name']}}</h1>
        @endfor
        @if(is_array($key))
            @foreach($key as $k=>$v)
                @foreach($v as $venue=>$place)
                        <h1>{{$v['venue']['addressLine1']}}</h1>
                        <h1>{{$v['venue']['addressLine2']}}</h1>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

and here is my output

```
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
14 Wandel Street
```

Comment: you have 2 foreach and the last one have no use

Answer (score 0):

Your second foreach have no use, try this one instead:

```
@foreach($datas as $data=>$key)
        @for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
            <h1>{{$datas[$data][$i]['name']}}</h1>
        @endfor
        @if(is_array($key))
            @foreach($key as $v)
                <h1>{{$v['venue']['addressLine1']}}</h1>
                <h1>{{$v['venue']['addressLine2']}}</h1>
            @endforeach
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Another improvement is to use the word `key` when the variable is a key from an array and not when is the value. And the `for` can be replaced too. Like this:

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
        <h1>{{ $data['name'] }}</h1>
        @if(is_array($key))
            @foreach($key as $v)
                <h1>{{ $v['venue']['addressLine1'] }}</h1>
                <h1>{{ $v['venue']['addressLine2'] }}</h1>
            @endforeach
        @endif
@endforeach
```